# An ios component that can be accessed from different apps on a device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am looking to achieve an implementation as below -

1. There are two ios apps installed on a device (assuming an iphone).
2. Each of these apps has a profile management screen of the user who is logged in.
3. If the same user is logged in on both the apps and makes changes to the profile settings, those changes should reflect on both the apps. (i.e. settings are overwritten)

I am aware that if there are settings changes for a single app, then the settings can be applied on multiple devices when the user is logged in to the same app. We can do this by invoking a service call (may be a REST based service).

The question here is, how do I make this possible for two apps without having service call? I mean, is it possible to create a component or may be an SDK so that it is scalable for future needs?

**EDIT:** I also need to implement multiple-app reusable 'settings screens' so that the same branding is applied across the apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the same storage across different apps on the same device you could use shared NSUserDefaults, or keychain.

Basically you need to open an "App Group" for you apps, either through Xcode in the project settings, or through iTunes Connect, and then use that shared group to store data for all of the apps that shares that group.

Please look at this guide for more information: [sharing data using app groups](http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/sharing-with-app-extensions)

**About your edit:**
If you want to use the same `.xib` files and `.h` and `.m` files, you can either create one Project, with multiple targets, and share some of the components, or you can dynamically load.

By dynamically loading I mean once one of the apps is installed, you can save the .xib and code to the shared storage, and then dynamically load it, however I would not recommend doing that, as it is prone to bugs.

If you want to read more about hot loading: [dynamically loading](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html)

Comment: thanks Eli, I added an EDIT to my question. Please could you look at it?

Comment: @LohithKorupolu I've added another section.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share simple data structures you can do it via iCloud. It's possible for two apps to share common data. Please refer to their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW26).

Comment: Ruchira, I added an EDIT to my question. Please could you look at it?

Comment: Hi Lohith, I believe that you can achieve this via iCloud because 
a) iCloud automatically syncs the values
b) If the same user logs in-to another device on the same app, then again it will be synced.

However, the issue is that you will need to be logged into the same Apple  account. Would that be okay for you?